# how to replace NumberInt(1) to 1 with vim?

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I want to replace `NumberInt(1)` to `1` except in the string in my file with some tool:

```
"bz":NumberInt(1), "batch": NumberInt(2), "something": "something else NumberInt(1)"
"bz":NumberInt(1), "batch": NumberInt(2), "something": "something else NumberInt(2)"
"bz":NumberInt(1), "batch": NumberInt(2), "something": "something else NumberInt(3)"
"bz":NumberInt(1), "batch": NumberInt(2), "something": "something else NumberInt(4)"
"bz":NumberInt(1), "batch": NumberInt(2), "something": "something else NumberInt(5)"
```

to

```
"bz":1, batch: 1, "something": "something else NumberInt(1)"
"bz":1, batch: 1, "something": "something else NumberInt(2)"
"bz":1, batch: 1, "something": "something else NumberInt(3)"
"bz":1, batch: 1, "something": "something else NumberInt(4)"
"bz":1, batch: 1, "something": "something else NumberInt(5)"
```

so as you can see, I want to replace the NumberInt except which is wrap with `"` or `'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
:%s/\vNumberInt\((\d+)\)/\1/
```

Using *very magic* mode (`\v`), do grouping in the number between parentheses and use it in the replacement part as backreference (`\1`):

It yields:

```
"bz":1, "something": "something else NumberInt(1)"
"bz":1, "something": "something else NumberInt(2)"
"bz":1, "something": "something else NumberInt(3)"
"bz":1, "something": "something else NumberInt(4)"
"bz":1, "something": "something else NumberInt(5)"
```

---

**UPDATE**: Use an alternative tool, like [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/NumberInt(\([0-9]\+\))/\1/' infile
```

It yields same result than before. The regular expression is similar, but using `[0-9]` because `\d` is not [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) compatible, and escape parens because they are not special.

**UPDATE 2**: Try the following:

```
sed 's/\(: *\)NumberInt(\([0-9]\+\))/\1\2/g' infile
```

It replaces all `NumberInt()` preceded by a semicolon, without double quotes between them.

Comment: sorry, do you have some better tools to deal with large file? I tried to replace with vim, then I find it is very very slow.

Comment: @roger: Done with `sed`. I hope it to be fast enough.

Comment: in fact I think if you deal a file like this, your solution may not be ok, `"bz":NumberInt(1), "batch": NumberInt(1), "something": "something else NumberInt(5)"`

Comment: @roger: What does *may not be ok* mean?

Comment: your method output is `"bz":1, "batch": NumberInt(1), "something": "something else NumberInt(5)"`, but I do want `"bz":1, "batch": 1, "something": "something else NumberInt(5)"`, so to be clearly, I want to delete all NumberInt except in string

Comment: @roger: That's far more complex of what you point out in your question. Update it with this case, so I can see the way to solve it.